# Locating 1912 Russian town of Novoe Kurhane

Tags: russia, 1910s, historical-gazetteer

My grandfather came to USA in 1912. In his Federal Naturalization record he said his town was Novoe Kurhane in Russia. I can't find the town on maps.

Does anyone know where Novoe Kurhane was or possibly the town's name was changed?

Does anyone know other sites where I might be able to find that town?

Comment: I wonder if it might be [Nowy Korczyn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowy_Korczyn), which is in modern Poland, but was part of the Russian Empire before 1918.

Comment: OP, can you [edit] the question to include a scan of the section of the document where this town name is written?

Answer (score 5):

There are [several villages](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%B5) called Kurgan'e (Курганье) in present-day Russia and Belarus.

Yandex Maps has [a settlement called Kurgan'e,](https://yandex.ru/maps/?ll=29.201406%2C53.571662&mode=whatshere&whatshere%5Bpoint%5D=29.199914%2C53.581338&whatshere%5Bzoom%5D=14.79&z=14.79) a part of Vladimirovka village, in Klichev district, Mogilev oblast of Belarus, and a [bus stop called Novoe Kurgan'e](https://yandex.ru/maps/?ll=29.197553%2C53.577098&mode=poi&poi%5Bpoint%5D=29.197157%2C53.577323&poi%5Buri%5D=ymapsbm1%3A%2F%2Forg%3Foid%3D145966290734&z=19) nearby. [Wikimapia names that settlement](https://wikimapia.org/#lang=ru&lat=53.580379&lon=29.197519&z=16&m=w&show=/36069043/ru/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9A%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%B5&search=%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%B5) Novoe Kurgan'e, and the description of Wikimapia object says that previously Novoe Kurgan'e was a village on its own.

Also there is a village Staroe Kurgan'e nearby (Staroe means Old and Novoe means New; Staroe X and Novoe X are a very common pattern in village names in Russia and neighbour countries).

I also found a [site about a WWII partisan](https://www.moypolk.ru/pallasovka/soldiers/chuprina-nina-yakimovna) that says that she was born in 1923 in Novoe Kurgan'e of Klichev district, Mogilev oblast in Belarus, which also confirms that at that time there was a separate village with that name.

(Note that transition "g"->"h" is very common in slavic languages, especially for Belarussian or Ukrainian language speakers.)